# No map rendered in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I am trying to follow the Choropleth example by Scott Murray (shown in his text book)using a timezone geojson file. The problem is my map ain't getting rendered and the entire SVG is getting filled with green color. My code is below, and I would like to know if I'm doing anything wrong in rendering the map. I fill colors in the map using the values under each timezone.(shown in the picture below).

```
  <script>
  var width = 1000;
  var height = 600;

  var d = [];
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .translate([width/2, height/2])
                .scale([500]);

  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(colorbrewer.YlGn[9]);

  var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
                      .attr("width",width)
                      .attr("height",height);

  d3.json('scm-timezone.json', function(data){
  var com = data.commits;
  d.push(com);
  color.domain([
   d3.min(d[0]),
   d3.max(d[0])
  ]);

 d3.json("world.json", function(json){

 for(var i = 0;i < data.tz.length;i++){

  var dataTZ = data.tz[i];

  var commitValue = parseInt(data.commits[i]);

  for(var j = 0;j<json.features.length;j++){

    var jsonTZ = json.features[j].properties.description;

    if(dataTZ == jsonTZ) {

      json.features[j].properties.value = commitValue;

    }
  }
}
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter() 
    .insert("path")
    .attr("d",path)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      var val = d.properties.value;
      if(val){ return color(val); }
      else { return "white"; }
            });
        });
     });

</script>
```

And my world.json finally looks like this-

[image]

Comment: There could any number of things wrong, can you put up a fiddle or a gist as an example?

Comment: I suspect that your problem is in the `var projection = d3.geo.mercator().translate([width / 2, height / 2]).scale([500]);` block.  You only need to pass `scale` a scalar not an array (so remove the `[]`).  You may also need to set the centre of the map.  Try having a look at this [bl.ock]( http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5193723).

Comment: Changing the scale into a scalar didn' t quite help.
@BenLyall Here is the link to the gist 
https://gist.github.com/rithika/69cde45e4b3b4c3a3679

Comment: I fixed the issue. I was rendering the timezone json file in a wrong way so I fixed it. I will update the gist as well. Thank you